# quick help with an eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Hey I'm running short on time and I clearly have some dumb hole in my understanding of finding eigenvalues. There is a question and basically I have to find the eigenvalues of the unforced equation: $ \frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}+2y = 0$. Nice and easy. Except I am converting this thing into a matrix of a system, so I get $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & -2\end{bmatrix}$, and I end up with the polynomial $\lambda^2 + 2\lambda = \lambda(\lambda +2)= 0 \implies \lambda_1 = 0, \lambda_2 = -2%$. These are wrong according to the book and I believe them – why would an undamped oscillator have straight line solutions? I am wondering if there is a better way to get eigenvalues in a second order system, and what I am doing wrong in my current method. It's actually pretty scary because this should be super easy at this point in the class. Thanks

Comment: Check how you got your matrix. Turning into a first order system should give 
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\begin{bmatrix} y \\ y' \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} y \\ y' \end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You found the correct eigenvalues for the matrix, but the matrix itself is wrong. To convert a second order equation into a first order system, make a new variable $x = y'$, depending on $t$. Then we get a system,
\begin{cases} x' = 0x - 2y \\ y' = x + 0y. \end{cases}
As a matrix (as this is a linear system),
$$\begin{pmatrix}x' \\ y' \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0 & -2 \\1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}.$$
So, the correct matrix is
$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & -2 \\1 & 0\end{pmatrix},$$
which has complex eigenvalues $\pm \sqrt{2}i$. This gives the undamped oscillations you need.